# Avoid repetition in Schtasks in PowerSehll

Tags: python, powershell, ffmpeg, windows-task-scheduler

The question is simple, but it seems I have problems with the philosophy of Schtasks.

***Goal:***

Download an online stream only for 2 hours every day (using FFMPEG) when my favorite program is streaming; we can give a start and end date, but I am fine if it runs every day indefinitely.

***How:***

Schedule a task that runs a PowerShell script when the online program starts; of course this is what I came up with; feel free to make suggestions, if you have better ideas (maybe using Python).

***My Solution:***

```
schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN Task1 /TR "powershell.exe .\dl.ps1" /ST 18:00 /DU 02:00
```

where the dl.ps1 contains:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://185.23.131.187/live/flv:tv3 live=1" -c copy .\fileName.flv
```

***Problem:***

This task repeats itself after 10 minutes --- which is the default repetition time.

***Question***

How do I achieve the goal and avoid the repetition? Maybe my mindset about duration, /DU, and repetition interval, /RI, is wrong.

***Bonus question***

I would like to change the name of each recorded file, i.e., fileName, based on the day of recording. How do I do that in PowerShell?

I have seen a solution that requires exporting the task to XML file. I was hoping that we could come up with a more elegant solution, if possible.

Comment: IMHO you should parse the channel schedule somewhere, then set up one task with many triggers of "once" and set expiration date for that task. Once that expires, you run another (recurring most likely) task that would do the same job. `Get-Help New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` (not sure about PS/OS version for this cmdlet, most likely it's available in 8.1 but not aerlier)

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind elaborating the first part on how to parse the channel schedule? I am running windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `/DU` for duration (which according to the help text forces a default Repetition Interval of 10 minutes) use `/ET` for end time and `/K` to terminate the task at the end time:

```
schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN Task1 /TR "powershell.exe .\dl.ps1" /ST 18:00 /ET 20:00 /K
```

To change the name of the file based on the date of recording, you can use `Get-Date` via a Subexpression `$()` in your PowerShell script with the `-Format` parameter like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://185.23.131.187/live/flv:tv3 live=1" -c copy ".\$(get-date -format 'dd-MM-yyyy').flv"
```

Comment: Thank you. The task that you suggested starts running the moment it is scheduled. I can't think why this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Try putting quotes around the times

Comment: Is it perhaps currently already past the specified start time where you are but before the end time?

Comment: No, it is not past the time and this task also repeats every 10 minutes :( Any ideas how to stop that?